# MySQL counting null values

Tags: mysql, count, null, missing-data

I am trying to count specific outcomes of a variable. It is region data and I have missings there, which I believe are skipped when trying to calculate a ratio.

```
select date
count( case when region in ('') and sale=1 then id end),
count( case when region in ('') and sale=1 then id end)/ count(id)
from region
group by 1;
```

The count for missings ('') is 0 (but I know there are missings), what is the way in mysql to indicate missings?

Comment: sample data and an example of expected output would go a long ways to clarifying the specification. It's not clear what is missing. It sounds like we might be wanting to return rows with `date` values that don't exist in `region`... but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include null values you can do:

```
select date
count( case when (region in ('') or region is null) and sale=1 then id end),
count( case when (region in ('') or region is null) and sale=1 then id end)
  / count(id)
from region
group by 1;
```